Segmentize vs Densify
Recently an edit to the tag segmentize got approved:

An operation which consist of adding vertices to line segments based
on maximum segment length.

And densify was declared as a synonym of it.
I may be wrong, but I disagree. To my knowledge:

segmentize is a process of dividing a geometry into pieces (often, but not neccessarily of equal length/size)
densify is a process of adding additional vertices to a geometry

Also the QGIS and ArcGIS links from the tag description define it that way in my opinion. To my opinion the interpretation/naming of shapely is incorrect.
Additonaly source: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Segmentize.html
Should the tag description be changed?

Good catch @MrXsquared!
I was at the origin of this tag because it was missing to me at the moment I wrote down a question.
I was not quite sure which to use and I fall back on segmentize because it was intuitively closer to a meaning of "cutting" or "splitting" something into smaller pieces in my mother language.
The tool I was searching a segmentation related answer was shapely and in its own documentation it doesn't use densify but only segmentize: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.segmentize.html
That's why, originally, I simply created the segmentize tag.
But in other softwares you may find other names, such as in QGIS which uses both words (but for different algorithms actually):

And from what I quickly saw in the literature, segmentation is more related to converting a curve to some discrete linear segment (changing the shape of the original feature) while densification is related to "adding" vertices without changing the feature's shape.
In GRASS GIS you may also meet an algorithm called i.segment but this one is related to image segmentation, which is something other, but still with the idea of cutting something (the image) into smaller pieces (classes of different objects). While it use v.split to densify...
So I totally agree for clarifying all that, whatever way you think is better but it seems there is apparently no clear consent in the GIS world nowadays...
But you may also want to ping shapely's developpers so that they can consider updating their wording in the future. ;)

I haven't found a discussion about it... but most likely shapely.segmentize was named like that to mimic the naming in postgis: ST_Segmentize
The c++ library that shapely wraps actually uses Densify for this functionality.

Segmentation is a form of densification.
In my opinion densify should be the main tag and segmentize the synonym.
However, there may be insufficient value to the tags. They would see an extremely low volume of questions.
